# How to exclude a record from sql with specific value

Tags: sql

I have a question about my sql query. I need to exclude all the rows that have the value 'f' in it.

I have tried doing

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE type NOT IN ('f')
```

But this doesnt seem to be working. Any help would  be appreciated

EDIT: sorry for being unclear,

The problem I have is that theres multiple rows like this

```
name   type

test1  f
test1  l
```

If i would use this query it would still return me test1 but what I want is that it returns NULL. Can this be done?

Comment: For completeness, can you specify a couple of sample records and indicate which should be included/excluded in the results?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using ?

Comment: what mean `isnt working` Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear. Please read edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You apparently want to see rows where no other rows for the same name has the value `f`

```
select t1.*
from the_table t1
where not exists (select *
                  from the_table t2
                  where t1.name = t2.name 
                    and t2.type = 'f');
```

If no such row exists the query will not return `null` it will simply return no rows at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `HAVING` clause :

```
SELECT s.name 
FROM YourTable s
GROUP BY s.name
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN s.type = 'f' THEN 1 END) = 0
```